# Triangulation, from calibrateCameras()s' tvec and rvec

Tags: opencv, triangulation, camera-calibration, projection-matrix

its hard too find exactly the answer to my question, that's why I want to ask it here, even it is poorly explained somewhere else. I try to add the solution in code so that everyone can get back to my results.
But first it has to be solved.

Its about triangulation with OpenCV `cv::triangulatePoints()`. I know its poor documented but it can be found at willowgarage (now) (search for the documentation 2.4.9)

1. I use for a chessboard calibration 22 stereo images (two cams) of
   different angles ect. for a stable intrinsic parameters.
2. got the chessboard corners with `cv::findChessboardCorners()`
3. optional - `cv::cornerSubPix()`
4. create objectPoints `cv::Point3f( k*m_squareSize, j*m_squareSize,0.0f)` over all chessboardpoints (k - chessboard width, j chessboard height or vice versa, with squareSize = realworld size)
5. do 2.-4. for every image
6. put everything in here: `cv::calibrateCamera(object_points1, image_points1, image.size(), intrinsic1, distCoeffs1, rvecs1, tvecs1);` this function works perfect like i wanted, i am doing it with the second camera images too. After long research I found this:
7. `cv::Mat R12 = R2*R1.t(); cv::Mat T12 =  T2-R*T1;` This is for the relationship (R|T) between cam1 & cam2. This works pretty well, I've tested it with the results of `cv::stereoCalibrate()`.
8. At this step I wanted to use my tvecs and rvecs for a re-projection 2D too 3D and 3D too 2D. Last I got done with `cv::projectPoints(object_points1[i],rvecs1[i],tvecs1[i],intrinsic1, distCoeffs1, imagePoints1);` -> works fine - I got with 48*2*22 points a maximum from 2Pixel difference at only one single point. But know i can't go further with the triangulation from 2d too 3D.
   I have! too use `cv::triangulatePoints()`. How do i get this work???

What I have done so far trying without an good result: You first need the projectionmatrices P1 and P2.

```
cv::Matx34d P1 = cv::Matx34d(   R1.at<double>(0,0), R1.at<double>(0,1), R1.at<double>(0,2), tvecs1[0].at<double>(0),
                                R1.at<double>(1,0), R1.at<double>(1,1), R1.at<double>(1,2), tvecs1[0].at<double>(1),
                                R1.at<double>(2,0), R1.at<double>(2,1), R1.at<double>(2,2), tvecs1[0].at<double>(2));
```

sorry this looks heavy but its only the rotationmatrix (rodrigues(rvecs1,R1)) and the translationvector tvecs1. Is this wrong? do i have to inverse the rotationmatrix R1?

Next step: you need the imagePoints(Corners) in left and right image. These imagePoints are the undistorted corners which I got from findChessboardCorners().

After using `cv::triangulatePoints(P1, P2, cv::Mat(undisPt_set1).reshape(1,2), cv::Mat(undisPt_set2).reshape(1,2), point3d);`point3d is a "4D" point where the fourth parameter has too be eliminated by `convertPointsHomogeneous(point3d.reshape(4, 1), point3dCam1);`

This is what I have done so far - but its not working. 
Does somebody know what I am doing wrong? Any wrong thoughts at the last steps? I've tryied the math but I am not sure about the projectionMatrix P1 and P2. I know its built like [R|t], but is it my tvecs and tvecs? is it transposed or inverse? Any help would be great, but pls help me out with some code or clear steps - not with more links where I should read and think, I realy did a research, I have the learning OpenCV book, OpenCV2 cookbook, and Hartley and Zisserman here in front of me. But I can't get to it.

Comment: How is P1 and P2 defined? I saw somewhere else that P1=[i|0], and P2 is just the rotation and translation seen from Camera1 (like the difference of both cameras). When i translate this to my project, would this mean I have too add something to P1 - like my tvec and rvec - and P2 is P1+ [R|T](between Cam1 and Cam2 what I am calculating in step 7) ?

Comment: P1,R1are from cv::stereorectify